# Do I need both /boot and /boot/efi?

Tags: boot, partition

Here is the result of running `lsblk` on my machine

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
zram0       252:0    0   7.5G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 153.4G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p6 259:4    0  82.9G  0 part /home
                                      /
```

What confuses me is the fact that I have both a /boot and a /boot/efi.
Are both partitions needed? Can I safely delete one of them?

Answer (score 8):

> Some users choose to put the EFI partition at /boot, making configuration a little bit easier for Linux-only systems. But when dualbooting – even if it's two different Linux distros – I suggest having the EFI partition at /boot/efi. A separate /boot is usually unnecessary.)
>
> The EFI partition is required if you want to boot your system in UEFI mode. However, if you want UEFI-bootable Debian, you might need to reinstall Windows as well, since mixing the two boot methods is inconvenient at best.

[EFI Partition vs /boot partition](https://superuser.com/questions/520068/efi-partition-vs-boot-partition)

The `/boot` partition is used in legacy BIOS systems. It contains the bootloader and kernel images required for the system to boot.

The `/boot/efi` partition is used in UEFI systems and serves as the EFI System Partition (ESP). It stores EFI bootloaders and other EFI-related files.

If your system is configured to boot in UEFI mode, you need to keep the `/boot/efi` partition for the system to boot properly.

The ESP contains important files for the UEFI boot process, including the bootloader (e.g., GRUB or systemd-boot) and UEFI firmware files.

The `/boot` partition is not necessary in UEFI systems, but it can be used for storing kernel images and related files.

It would be helpful to know whether your system is configured to boot in legacy BIOS mode or UEFI mode.

If you are using UEFI mode and don't have any requirements for the `/boot` partition, it should be safe to delete it.

It's always recommended to make a backup of your data before making any changes to disk partitions.

[Select UEFI Boot Mode or Legacy BIOS Boot Mode (BIOS)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23161_01/html/E37044/glsem.html)

[EFI system partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition)

[What Is UEFI, and How Is It Different from BIOS?](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/)

https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/Unified-Extensible-Firmware-Interface-UEFI

**Full Disk Encryption**

If you are using full disk encryption or encrypted root partition, a separate `/boot` partition is necessary.

When using encryption, the boot process needs to access the necessary bootloader and kernel from an unencrypted `/boot` partition to allow the system to access files to decrypt the encrypted partitions and start the system.

[dm-crypt/Encrypting an entire system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system)

Comment: Thanks for telling that a separate, non encrypted /boot is required whatever the UEFI choice if the rest of the system is encrypted !